# How do I reset actor memory in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Braith still thinks her parents are deceased even after I resurrected them. I tried 'resetai','disable' followed by 'enable', 'recycleactor', base ID spawns... so pretty much everything *i think*.

Could any of you could tell me a way to totally and completely reset the character memory?

Is there a way?

Comment: There is most likely a hidden quest flag set when her parents die that needs to be reset - unfortunately, you probably need to trawl through the constructor set to figure out what that is

Comment: The Creation Kit should show relevant information, if you're on PC, as Chronocidal mentions, but also, are you running `recycleactor` on the parents or on Braith? If the former, try the latter instead.